# Use Pedometer on wearable Native application

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app

I need to get access to the data provided by the Pedometer (according to [this](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/guides/native-application/location-and-sensors/device-sensors#pedometer) site) on a wearable device (the Samsung Gear S3). It seems as if the Pedometer was accessible by a native app, but it also seems as if my programming skills weren't capable of figuring out how it works. Would anyone give me a hint, please?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to start from this [Tip & Tech Document](https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/how-use-light-sensor-tizen) in Tizen developers forum. This document explains step by step how to use device sensor in Tizen native application including creating event listener, registering callback functions, reading data, etc. You may download the [project (.zip)](https://developer.tizen.org/sites/default/files/documentation/lightsensor.zip) and import in Tizen Studio.

Light Sensor in mobile native is implemented here, but the process for Pedometer in wearable native is also the same, just change in some parameters. Add the healthinfo privilege and pedometer feature in your config.xml file.

```
<feature name="tizen.org/feature/sensor.pedometer"/>
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/healthinfo"/>
```

Check the [API references](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/3.0.0/org.tizen.native.wearable.apireference/group__CAPI__SYSTEM__SENSOR__MODULE.html) for details, you would find all the API functions there.